# iOS 10 Swift and best practices for defining the UI

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, storyboard, interface-builder

I'm working on an iOS app in Swift. The other app I created was one I did in Objective C and release around this time in 2014. Storyboards seem to have made UI stuff both easier and more complicated at the same time, so I'm trying to figure out current best practice in terms of view development.

Size classes and constraints seem like almost a necessary timesaver at this point for multiple screen sizes. Back in 2014, this was less the case, and programmatically keeping track of UI layouts as CGRect code made programmatically mucking with UI layout much simpler and better for code reuse vs creating a whole new view controller for just adding new UI elements to much the same view. Doing the same thing with constraint code seems less appealing, but also necessary if I want more code reuse there.

So I'm wondering what the current practice is here as I'm just thinking in terms of code reuse. Programmatic constraints just seem less elegant than storyboard defined ones, but I'm not sure they're the end all be all for UI code since they seem problematic for programmatically updating the UI on the fly.

Is the best strategy at this point to enclose everything in layout preserving superviews and keep most of this storyboard centric or would it still make sense to do swift programmatic code for these layouts since I'd have to for iPad and iPhone specific changes anyway? On that subject would it still make sense to split drastically different UIs into multiple storyboards (e.g. 2 different iPad and iPhone storyboards as that was a default at one point)?

Thanks in advance for answers to this. Device specific stuff just seems to not always be code reuse, but I just want reuse to be relatively simple I guess. Otherwise I'm just creating more swift classes than I strictly need.

Answer (score 3):

This is inherently opinion based. Everything from no Interface Builder to only StoryBoards is likely being used in production applications, and you can make just about anything work.

My personal tendency is to use Storyboards for everything other than TableView/CollectionView cells. I find it removes almost all interface boilerplate code from my classes and makes it so I only need to handle the interface between my ViewControllers. Here are the guidelines I generally try and follow: (again...opinion)

- Use multiple storyboards organized in a useful way:

Large storyboard become hard to maintain and performance while editing suffers noticeably. We have the option to use StoryboardReferences, so might as well use them.

- The more Scenes and ViewControllers, the better. (within reason)

This makes things more maintainable and re-usable. E.g. a header that could be used in multiple Scenes. It can be a bit annoying to have to use containerVCs and deal with segues everywhere, but I rarely regret separating something into it's own ViewController.

- Don't use separate interface files for different sizes.

It's more code to maintain and will force you to swap ViewControllers in-out if you want to support resizing on iPad (or any future devices). Not to mention going forward it's clear Apple is assuming you're using size classes rather than swapping ViewControllers and is clearly where the future is headed in Apple platforms development

- When you need animations, try and narrow it down to changing a single constraint.constant

This greatly simplifies your code and usually avoids having to deal with size-classes anywhere other than the storyboards. It's not always possible for complicated animations, but you can do a surprising amount if you're willing to mess around. It makes it possible to narrow down a toggling action to 2 lines of code, which is quite nice. Using StackViews can also help with this a lot.

The other thing to focus on is avoiding as much of the stringly-typed nature of IB as possible. This is much easier in Swift and there are some decent solutions using string-backed enums and extensions, but specifics are probably out of the scope of this question.